# Search Database for String Containing Characters

Tags: android, sqlite

I use the below code to search the exact string in the database. For example, if I would like to search for "abc", then I need to enter "abc".
What I intend to do is to enable the searching without the exact string. For example, I can enter "bc" and return the "abc" as the result. I tried to change the `englishWord.equals("")` to `englishWord.contains("")`. However, this is not work.

```
public List<Bean> getWords(String englishWord) {
        if(englishWord.equals(""))
            return new ArrayList<Bean>();

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ENGLISH + " LIMIT 100";

        SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{englishWord + "%"});

            List<Bean> wordList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                int id = cursor.getInt(0);
                String english = cursor.getString(1);
                String bangla = cursor.getString(2);
                String status = cursor.getString(3);
                wordList.add(new Bean(id, english, bangla, status));
            }

            return wordList;
        } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relace

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{englishWord + "%"});
```

with

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"%" + englishWord + "%"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use ("%" + englishWord + "%").The code is

```
 public List<Word> getWords(String englishWord) {

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
            " WHERE " + ENGLISH + " LIKE ? ORDER BY " + ENGLISH + " LIMIT 100";



    SQLiteDatabase db = initializer.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{"%" + englishWord + "%"});//Change here



        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String english = cursor.getString(1);
            String bangla = cursor.getString(2);
            String status = cursor.getString(3);
            wordList.add(new Word(id, english, bangla, status));
        }

        return wordList;
    } catch (SQLiteException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: "code only" answers are discouraged. Putting "try this" in front doesn't really help here.